# How do I get just the name of the image file in string from this code

Tags: php, string, image, post, upload

I have to get just the name of the file into a string.

Using this code:

```
<?php 

$target = "upload/"; 
$name="chekcs";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name'].$name); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
echo "yes";
} 
else {
echo "no";
}
?>
```

uploaded is the file im uploading.

I need just its name. Into a string.

How can I do that?

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Do **NOT** use this code. You opening your server to a TOTAL remote compromise with this.

Comment: which code do you suggest then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returns the original filename:

```
$_FILES['uploaded']['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

$_FILES is a predefined variable that will include things like the original filename, temporary name, and so on.

In order to access to Original filename, it is stored in the ['name'] key of the array.

```
<?php
$filename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
?>
```

From this filename you can grab extensions as well so you can do a check on it using [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/pathinfo)

```
<?php
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // $filename from above code
?>
```